# Need help in understanding Perl lookbehind to exclude and include a pattern

Tags: regex, perl

I only want the following output from the array above:

```
going pro
staying pro
```

The code I'm using below is not accomplishing this goal.

```
   my @proFilter = ("a pro linebacker","a pro review","the pro not playing like a pro","going pro","staying pro");

   foreach $textLine (@proFilter)
   {
     if($textLine =~ /((?<!\b(a|the)\b) pro [a-z]+)/g)
     {
       print "$1\n"; 
     }
   }
```

Comment: thanks for pointing this out, this side problem has been fixed. I'm still having the main problem.

Comment: What side problem?

Comment: One problem: lookbehinds have to be fixed-width. You can have alternatives with 1 and 3 characters. The main problem is that you're not matching the word before `pro`, you have `[a-z]+` after it.

Comment: thanks for pointing this out but I'm still confused with your answer. Can you please provide me an example for an easier understanding

Comment: use a **lookahead** instead of **lookbehind** check this [demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/fr/regex-tester/d5c4af749bcb)

Comment: Variable-length look-behinds were added in Perl 5.29.9. They have a limited maximum width, though.

Comment: @Barmar, Re "*One problem: lookbehinds have to be fixed-width.*", Not anymore, although there's a limit how bar they will look. This case is firmly within that limit, though.

Comment: @user20284150 [regular-expression.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) says that they were added as an experimental feature in 5.30, but "there are many cases in which it does not work correctly.". Has that been resolved?

Comment: They are no longer experimental as of Perl 5.36, except for cases where they contain capturing parentheses, according to [perl5360delta](https://perldoc.perl.org/perl5360delta.html). As for the "many cases where it dies not work correctly," can you give examples? The web page you cite does not, so I can not address your question except to say that I have never encountered cases where they have worked incorrectly. Sometimes they do not work the way I would like them to (e.g. `(?<=\w+)`), but that is not the same as "working incorrectly."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of a lookbehind, use a lookahead, and combine it with `[a-z]+` to match a word that isn't `a` or `the`.

```
/(\b(?!(?:a|the)\b)[a-z]+) pro/g
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/v5nXDe/1)

Comment: Two of those `\b` are uneeded. Fixed: `/(\b(?!(?:a|the)\b)[a-z]+) pro/g`

Answer (score 1):

Your regex matches `pro` + space + one or more lowercase ASCII letters, that is always preceded with a space that is not immediately preceded with `a` or `the` whole word. Note that your pattern can't match `going pro` and `staying pro` not just because of a lookbehind but also due to the presence of `[a-z]+`.

As for the fixed-width lookbehind pattern issue, all you need is to match the  patterns you want to avoid matching and apply `(*SKIP)(*F)`:

```
\b(?:a|the)\s+pro\b(*SKIP)(*F)|\bpro\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/H5rvst/1).

*Details*:

- `\b(?:a|the)\s+pro\b(*SKIP)(*F)`:

  - `\b` - word boundary
  - `(?:a|the)` - a non-capturing group matching `a` or `the` words
  - `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
  - `pro` - a word
  - `\b` - another word boundary
  - `(*SKIP)(*F)` - two verbs that make the regex engine fail at the current location and go on to search for the next match from this failure location (not from the next position in the string)
- `|` - or
- `\bpro\b` - a whole word `pro`.